# Does anyone know what the digital equivalent of analog pins 0-15 on a Mega 2560 is?

Tags: arduino

I am a beginner of Arduino. here I am facing a problem to declare analog pins. Can I use 97 to 82 int value instead of A0 to A15. If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use 97 to 82 int value instead of A0 to A15

No, that is not the correct range. From https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.4/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/mega/pins_arduino.h#L51-L83:

```cpp
#define PIN_A0   (54)
#define PIN_A1   (55)
#define PIN_A2   (56)
#define PIN_A3   (57)
#define PIN_A4   (58)
#define PIN_A5   (59)
#define PIN_A6   (60)
#define PIN_A7   (61)
#define PIN_A8   (62)
#define PIN_A9   (63)
#define PIN_A10  (64)
#define PIN_A11  (65)
#define PIN_A12  (66)
#define PIN_A13  (67)
#define PIN_A14  (68)
#define PIN_A15  (69)

static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;
static const uint8_t A1 = PIN_A1;
static const uint8_t A2 = PIN_A2;
static const uint8_t A3 = PIN_A3;
static const uint8_t A4 = PIN_A4;
static const uint8_t A5 = PIN_A5;
static const uint8_t A6 = PIN_A6;
static const uint8_t A7 = PIN_A7;
static const uint8_t A8 = PIN_A8;
static const uint8_t A9 = PIN_A9;
static const uint8_t A10 = PIN_A10;
static const uint8_t A11 = PIN_A11;
static const uint8_t A12 = PIN_A12;
static const uint8_t A13 = PIN_A13;
static const uint8_t A14 = PIN_A14;
static const uint8_t A15 = PIN_A15;
```

So as you can see, the values of `A0` through `A15` are 54 through 69.

Can you use those numbers instead of the A*n* pin names? Yes.

You can also use the analog channel number with analogRead().
For example the following three statements all read pin A0:

```
analogRead(A0)
```

and:

```
analogRead(54)
```

and:

```
analogRead(0)
```

But really it's less confusing just to use the pin names that are written on the silkscreen of your Arduino board.

> If yes then how?

Exactly as you would with the A*n* pin names.

Comment: but here I got this...they suggest 97 to 82 as a substance of A0 to A15. Would you please explain this what they want to describe in this link... https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping2560

Comment: Those are physical pin numbers. They just note the number of the physical pins on the chip starting at 1 from the top left corner going clockwise. They can not be used in your code and it would not make sense to do so since some of those pins are things like VCC and ground pins.